# Showing that a transitive abelian permutation group is necessarily regular

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am trying to show that a transitive, abelian permutation group acting on a set $X$ is necessarily regular, given this hint: 'Given $g \in G$, consider the set $X^g:=\{x \in X\,|\,gx=x\}$.  Show that if $G$ is transitive and abelian, then the only possibilities for $X^g$ are $\varnothing$ or $X$.'

I know that $X^g=X$ iff $g$ is the identity of $G$.  And...that's about all I've got.  I don't even see how, once the above is shown to be true, the result follows.

I would really appreciate some *hints* to help me in the right direction.

This is from Isaacs' Algebra: A Graduate course.  He introduces permutation groups first, but group actions haven't entered the scene yet.  I am alright with a hint in terms of actions though.

Thanks!

Comment: A transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is regular if and only if $\#G=\#X$. So the question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128098/61691

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Let $1\not=g \in G$ and suppose $gx=x$ for some $x\in X$.  Then take another element $y\in X$.  Using the fact that $G$ is transitive, we have that some other element $h\in G$ such that $hy=x$.  Now use the fact that $G$ is abelian to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Does this work?  Suppose $1 \ne g \in G$, and $gx=x$ for some $x \in X$.  Then for some $x \ne y \in X$, there exists another element $h \in G$ such that $hy=x$.  But then $gx=x \Rightarrow gx=hy \Rightarrow h^{-1}gx=y \Rightarrow gh^{-1}x=y \Rightarrow gy=y$.  But $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, so $g$ must be the identity, contradicting our assumption that $g \ne 1$.  So for $g \ne 1$ we must have $X^g=\varnothing$.

Comment: @AlexPetzke You got it!

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* You know $G$ is a permutation group, so only the identity fixes every point. Furthermore, you know that the intersection 
$$
\bigcap_{x \in X} G_{x}
$$
of the stabilizers $G_{x} = \{ g \in G : g x = x \}$ is exactly the set of elements in $G$ that fix every point, so it is $\{ 1 \}$.

*Spoiler*

> Now you know $G$ to be transitive on $X$. So once you fix $x_{0} \in X$, you will have $X = \{ g x_{0} : g \in G \}$. Thus $$\{1\} = \bigcap_{x \in X} G_{x} = \bigcap_{g \in G} G_{g x_{0}} = \bigcap_{g \in G} g G_{x_{0}} g^{-1} = \dots$$

Comment: I'm not seeing where this is going (the spoiler wasn't much of a spoiler for me)...could you explain?

Comment: @AlexPetzke, the stabilizers are all conjugate (since the group acts transitively), so they are the same in an abelian group. Thus the stabilizer of a single point fixes all points, and thus must be $\{ 1\}$, so that the group acts regularly.

Comment: I'm not used to all the details of group actions yet, but with some help from Wikipedia, I get it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given $G \le Sym(X)$ is transitive and abelian, to show $G$ is regular, it suffices to show $G$ is semiregular, i.e. to show that $G_x=1$ for some $x \in X$.  In other words, we need to show that if $g \in G$ fixes any element $x$, then it fixes all the remaining elements also, i.e. that $X^g=X$ or $=\phi$, $\forall g \in G$.

Suppose $g \in G$ fixes an element $x \in X$.  So $x^g=x$.  Let $y \in X$.  We show $g$ fixes $y$ also. By transitivity of $G$, there is some $h \in G, h: x \mapsto y$. Hence $y^g = x^{hg}=x^{gh}=x^h=y$, where $hg=gh$ because $G$ is abelian. Thus, $g=1$ (i.e. $X^g=X$).

Answer (score -1):

Complete set of hints:

1. What is the invariant subset $X^{g}=\{g\in G\mid g(x)=x\}$ like when…

   a. $g=e$?

   b. $g\ne e$?
2. For any fixed $x,y\in X$, there certainly exists $h\in G$ such that $h(x)=y$.
   What is $T=\{g\in G\mid g(x)=y\}$ and how many elements are there in $T$?

   a. Keep in mind that the goal is to show that the permutation group $G$ on $X$ is regular.  What properties must $T$ have?

   b. To help this part of the proof, note the striking resemblance between $\{g\in G\mid g(x)=x\}$ and $\{g\in G\mid g(x)=y\}$.

Answer (score -3):

Let $gx=y$, $hx=y$, where $g,h$-elements of the group $G$; $x,y$-elements of the set $A$. $G$ acts on $A$
Let $t$ some element of $A$. As $G$-transitive,there exist $f$ in $G$ that
$t=fx$ As $G$ is abelian we have:
$$gt=g(fx)=(gf)x=(fg)x=f(gx)=fy=f(hx)=(fh)x=(hf)x=h(fx)=ht$$
So for any $t$ in $A$ we have $gt=ht$, so $g=t$, then $G$-regular