# Proving equivalence of a tree-based version of Countable Choice for families of finite sets.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

In [this paper](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.Good/research/pdfs/horror.pdf) by Good and Tree, the following result is mentioned without proof as part of Proposition 6.5:

> *Each of the following statements imply those beneath it.*
>
> - *The countable union of finite sets is countable.*
> - *Every $\omega$-tree has an infinite chain or an infinite antichain.*
> - *Every countable collection of* [non-empty] *finite sets has a choice function.*

I know that the first and last statements are equivalent, so that these statements are ostensibly all equivalent. I'm stymied on proving the second implication, though.

I began by taking $\{X_n:n<\omega\}$ to be a countably-infinite collection of finite non-empty sets, putting $X=\bigcup_{n<\omega}X_n,$ and letting $$T=\left\{f\in{}^{<\omega}X:\forall n\in\operatorname{dom}(f)\:f(n)\in X_n\right\},$$ where ${}^{<\omega}X$ is the set of all functions $k\to X$ with $k<\omega$. It is readily shown that $\langle T,\subsetneq\rangle$ is an $\omega$-tree. Now, if the tree has an infinite chain $C,$ then $$B=\bigcup_{f\in C}\{g\in T:g\subsetneq f\}$$ is a branch of length $\omega,$ and $f=\bigcup B$ is readily the desired choice function. On the other hand, if the tree has no infinite chain, then it has an infinite antichain, say $A.$ If $A$ happens to be Dedekind-infinite, then there is a countably-infinite antichain $A'\subseteq A,$ and without loss of generality, we may assume that $A'$ has at most one node on each level. Indexing the elements of $A'$ in order of increasing level by $f_n,$ we define $g(X_k)=f_0(k)$ for $k\in\operatorname{dom}(f_0)$ and $g(X_k)=f_{n+1}(k)$ where $k\in\operatorname{dom}(f_{n+1})\setminus\operatorname{dom}(f_n).$ Then $g$ is the desired choice function, and we're done.

If $A$ is infinite and Dedekind-finite, then...what in the world can be done? We need another (even stronger!) Choice principle to conclude that this is impossible, thereby finishing my proof.

Any hints as to how I can proceed?

---

**Added**: To see that the first statement implies the second, suppose we are given an $\omega$-tree $T.$ We know $T$ is countably-infinite since each of its countably-infinitely-many non-empty levels is finite. Let $f:\omega\to T$ a bijection. Supposing that $T$ has no infinite antichain, let $A$ be the set of all nodes of $T$ without successor. Since this is readily an antichain, then it is finite, so, put $$m=\max\bigl(\{0\}\cup\{k<\omega:A\cap T_k\ne\emptyset\}\bigr).$$ Let $c_0\in T_{m+1}.$ Given $c_n$ with height greater than $m$, we have by definition of $A$ and $m$ that $c_n$ has a successor, and letting $$c_{n+1}=f\bigl(\min\{k<\omega:c_n<f(k)\}\bigr),$$ the height of $c_{n+1}$ is greater than that of $c_n$, so also greater than $m$. In this way, we recursively define a strictly increasing sequence of points of $T$, so we have an infinite chain, as desired.

To see that the third statement implies the first, suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable set of finite sets. For each $A\in\mathcal A,$ we have that $A$ is well-orderable, and in particular can be put into bijection with a unique finite ordinal--namely $|A|.$ There are only finitely-many functions $A\to|A|,$ at least one of which is a bijection, and so the set $B_A$ of bijections $A\to|A|$ is a non-empty finite set for each $A\in\mathcal A.$ Since $\mathcal A$ is countable, then we can therefore use a choice function on $\{B_A:A\in\mathcal A\}$ to choose a bijection $g_A:A\to|A|$ for each $A\in\mathcal A.$ Using these bijections, we can readily show that $$\left|\bigcup\mathcal A\right|\le\sum_{A\in\mathcal A}|A|.$$ Then, since $\mathcal A$ is well-orderable and each $|A|$ is a finite cardinal, then $$\sum_{A\in\mathcal A}|A|\le\max\left\{|\mathcal A|,\sup_{A\in\mathcal A}|A|\right\}\le\aleph_0,$$ whence $\bigcup\mathcal A$ is countable, as desired.

---

If "Dedekind-finite = finite" holds, then showing the second statement implies the third is simple, but according to the paper, the implication is supposed to hold in $\mathsf{ZF}.$ It's possible that this was simply an error on the authors' part (like leaving off the "non-empty" from the third statement), and that it should specify *Dedekind-infinite* antichains.

If it is correct, though, then my approach quite simply won't work, since given an arbitrary infinite antichain, it need not have a countably-infinite subset. Certainly any such antichain will be a union of a countably-infinite collection of non-empty finite sets, but it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that a countably-infinite union of pairs may be Dedekind-finite.

My question is this: Is it known whether the second statement (as originally written) is equivalent to or strictly weaker than the other two in $\mathsf{ZF}$? If it is equivalent, then can you direct me to a source in which it is proved, or outline an alternate proof technique that does the trick?

---

[Cross-posted to [Math.Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143524/22840).]

Comment: In one Guinness and ten minutes I will post an answer.  I hope. ;)

Comment: (I had to stop for a hot dog. The Viennese fast food stands are divine... So it took a few minutes longer!)

Comment: Ha! I was thinking: "My, that must be a big Guinness!"

Comment: Well, it was the third Guinness, with the addition of two whisky in between. So it was longer than the first Guinness...

Comment: Could someone please either define or link to a definition of $\omega$-tree?

Comment: Apologies, @dfeuer. An $\omega$-tree is a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(set_theory)) of height $\omega$ such that every level is finite--equivalently, every node has finite degree (every element of the tree has only finitely-many successors).

Comment: If by antichain they mean strong antichain, would that provide some useful partition?

Comment: @dfeuer: It certainly would, since a strong antichain would have at most one element, as the root is a common lower bound for all nodes in a tree. My suspicion at this point is that Good and Tree were simply being sloppy, and that they meant "*countably*-infinite antichain," mistakenly assuming that every infinite set has a countably-infinite subset. It's a fairly weak Choice principle, and rather widely accepted, so it's an understandable mistake. Still, in a paper talking about consistency of results without Choice, I'd hope for more caution.

Comment: Why don't you ask them and let us know?

Comment: @dfeuer: Well, *that's* certainly a thought. I suppose that would be the best way to proceed, actually.

Comment: May I ask what your method is for a *countable* antichain?

Comment: @dfeuer: I added it to the post this morning (in the paragraph where I first mentioned it). Have a look and see what you think.

Comment: And now I miss Vienna... :(

Comment: @Asaf: My apologies! I hope that your journey down memory lane was a pleasant one, at least. Vienna is quite lovely.

Comment: Oh my, I love Vienna. I can't wait for my next visit there!

Comment: Cameron, did you ever get in touch with the authors?

Comment: @dfeuer: No, I never did. Guess I should just bite the bullet and hit them up via snail mail, since I wasn't able to find any other means of contacting them.

Comment: Chris Good is apparently now at the University of Birmingham. His email address can be found on [his page there](http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/staff/profiles/maths/good-christopher.aspx). I wasn't able to find any more contact info for Ian J. Tree.

Comment: @dfeuer: Many thanks! I will make contact and report back on what I find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a permutation model satisfying:

> Form 216: every $\omega$-tree has an infinite chain or infinite antichain

but not

> Form 10: countable unions of finite sets are countable

By Pincus’ transfer result [1] this means there is no implication in ZF, unless ZF is inconsistent. Form 216 (plus the negation of Form 217) is actually given as an example of a transferable statement - see 2B5 on page 724 of [1]. My impression is that Form 216 is only of interest for appearing in Pincus’ dissertation, and in this mistake in the Good-Tree paper.

Rather than talk about antichains, for the following arguments it will be easier to obtain a related object: a “nowhere dense” subtree. A **subtree** of a tree is a downwards-closed subset. A subtree $T_0\subset T$ is **nowhere dense** if for every $t_0\in T_0$ there is $t>t_0$ with $t\in T\setminus T_0.$ (This is not standard terminology.)

**Lemma.** Any $\omega$-tree $T$ with an infinite nowhere dense subtree $T_0$ has an infinite antichain.

*Proof:* Take the antichain $D$ of minimal elements of $T\setminus T_0.$ For each $n,$ there is an element $t_0\in T_0$ of height $n,$ and since $T_0$ is nowhere dense there must be some $t>t_0$ not in $T_0.$ A minimal such $t$ is an element of $D$ of height at least $n+1.$ This shows that $D$ has elements of arbitrarily large heights, which means $D$ is infinite. $\square$

(The reverse implication also holds: given an infinite antichain $D,$ take $T_0$ to be the set of elements $t\in T$ such that there are infinitely many $d\in D$ with $d>t.$)

Enumerate the primes as $p_1,p_2,\dots.$ The set of atoms $A$ has an element $a(n,i)$ for each $n\geq 1$ and each $i\in\mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z.$ The group of permutations is the product $G=\prod_n (\mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z),$ acting by $\pi(a(n,i))=a(n,i+\pi_n).$ Let $\mathcal S$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb N$ of zero [upper density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Upper_and_lower_asymptotic_density). For each $S\in\mathcal S$ define the subgroup $G(S)$ of permutations $\pi$ with $\pi_n=0$ for all $n\in S.$

This data $(A,G,\{G(S):S\in\mathcal S\})$ defines a permutation model $N.$ A good reference for permutation models is Jech’s “Set Theory”, but I’ll give a very informal brief description. Working from a model of ZFC, we construct a universe of sets $V$ built from $A$ by the operations of taking power sets and subsets. $V$ is a model of ZFA (ZF with atoms, also known as ZFU) satisfying the axiom of choice. The permutation action of $\pi\in G$ extends to an action on these sets. A set is “symmetric” if there exists $S$ such that $G(S)$ fixes $x,$ so $x=\pi x$ for all $\pi\in G(S).$ We restrict the universe to sets $x$ which are *hereditarily* symmetric, recursively defined as: $x$ is symmetric, and each element of $x$ is hereditarily symmetric. We don’t require the same $S$ to be used for different elements. This produces the permutation model $N,$ which satisfies ZFA. Existence arguments can be carried out in $V,$ with a verification that the result actually exists in $N.$

The sequence of finite sets $A_n=\{a(n,i):i\in\mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z\}$ exists in $N.$ We’ll show that their union is not countable. Given a function $f:\mathbb N\mapsto \bigcup A_n$ fixed by $G(S),$ pick $n\not\in S$ and $\pi\in G(S)$ with $\pi_n\neq 0.$ We cannot have $f(k)=a(n,0)$ for any $k,$ because then $f(k)=(\pi f)(\pi k)=\pi(a(n,0))=a(n,\pi_n)\neq f(k).$ So Form 10 fails in $N.$

A nice feature of this model is that symmetries of finite sets have a simple classification. A highbrow description is that we’re using automatic continuity for a profinite topology. Consider a $S\in\mathcal S$ and an $x\in N$ such that the orbit $G(S)x$ has a finite cardinality $m.$ Let $X$ be the set of indices $n\in\mathbb N\setminus S$ such that $p_n$ divides $m.$ Since permutation actions of abelian groups are regular, the stabilizer is well-defined and has index $m.$ The action therefore factors through $G(S)/mG(S).$ But this group has cardinality at most $m,$ because the second summand below is $m$-divisible so gets included in $mG(S)$:
$$G(S)=(\prod_{n\in X} \mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z)\times (\prod_{n\in S\setminus X} \mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z).$$
The first summand is forced to have order $m,$ which means $m$ is the product of its prime factors, $\prod_{n\in X} p_n.$ The first summand acts freely and transitively, while the second summand acts trivially. Note that $X$ is the unique minimal set such that $x$ is fixed by $G(S\cup X).$

Consider an $\omega$-tree $(T,<)$ in $N$ fixed by some $G(S_T),$ and assume that $T$ has no infinite chain in $N.$ We aim to show that there is an infinite nowhere dense subtree of $T$ in $N.$

Pick an infinite chain $x_0<x_1<\dots$ in $T.$ For $n\in\omega$ let $X_n$ be the unique minimal finite set such that $x_n$ is fixed by $G(S_T\cup X_n).$ These form a non-decreasing chain $X_0\subseteq X_1\subseteq \dots$ because any tree automorphism that moves a parent node must move all its child nodes. Let $X_\infty=\bigcup X_n.$ We cannot be in the situation $X_\infty\in\mathcal S$ because that would imply $S_T\cup X_\infty\in\mathcal S,$ which would mean that the chain $\{x_i:i\in\omega\}$ is in $N.$

Pick any infinite $S\subset X_\infty$ of zero upper density, for example $S=\bigcup_n \min\{i\in X_\infty: i\geq n^2\}.$ I claim that the subtree
$$T_0=\{\pi x_i : \pi\in G(S_T\cup S), i \in \omega\}\subset T$$
is nowhere dense. To verify this we need to show that for each $\pi\in G(S_T\cup S)$ and each $i \in \omega$ there exists $t>\pi x_i$ with $t\not\in T_0.$ By applying $\pi^{-1}$ to both sides we can assume $\pi$ is the identity. For large enough $j>i$ there exists $n\in (X_j\setminus X_i) \cap S.$ The action of $G(S_T\cup S\setminus \{n\})$ on its orbit of $x_j$ factors through the group $$H=\prod_{k\in \{n\}\cup (X_j\setminus S)} \mathbb Z/p_k\mathbb Z.$$ $H$ acts regularly on the orbit $Hx_j,$ so the orbit $G(S_T\cup S\setminus \{n\})x_j$ is $p_n$ times larger than $G(S_T\cup S)x_j.$ Pick any $t$ in the former but not the latter, for example $t=\sigma x_j$ where $\sigma_n=1$ and $\sigma_m=0$ for $m\neq n.$

$T_0$ is in $N,$ and it’s an infinite nowhere dense subtree of $T.$ By the Lemma, we have verified that Form 216 holds in $N.$

[1] Zermelo-Fraenkel Consistency Results by Fraenkel-Mostowski Methods, David Pincus, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 37, No. 4 (Dec., 1972), pp. 721-743

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've had very limited exposure to permutation models, so it will likely take me time to sort through it all. I'll ask questions as they occur to me. Off-hand, I have only two. (1) For the reverse implication of the Lemma, wouldn't it be simpler to take $T_0$ to be the downward closure of $D,$ less the elements of $D$? (2) Regarding picking an infinite chain in $T,$ are we able to do that due to the fact that Choice holds in the model of $V,$ or for some other reason?

Comment: @CameronBuie: (1) Yes, that's a better argument. (2) Yes, I should say that step is using Kőnig's lemma in $V$

Comment: Does this model have a name, by chance?

Comment: @CameronBuie: I don't think so, but it could be seen as a modification of "Levy's model I", $\mathcal N6$ in Howard-Rubin

Comment: @CameronBuie: I didn't understand the issue - if you are pressed for space perhaps you would like to email me, hwestmaths at gmail dot com ? I might take a couple of days to respond.

Comment: Apologies! I decided to stop cluttering the comments. :-) I may e-mail you once I've got things more fleshed out, or I may add my workings to the answer I posted above for simplicity. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've been wrestling with it for the past several days, and I've made no headway in understanding the sentence: "The action therefore factors through $G(S)/mG(S).$ I know that $mG(S)$ and the stabilizer of $x$ are (normal) subgroups of $G(S).$ I also know that if $\phi:G\to\operatorname{Perm}(V)$ is the action of $G,$ then "factors through" means there is a homomorphism $\psi:G(S)/mG(S)\to\operatorname{Perm}(V)$ such that $\phi\restriction_{G(S)}=\psi\circ\pi,$ where $\pi:G(S)\to G(S)/mG(S)$ is the canonical projection. I can't see why, and none of my Google searches has shed any light.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Sorry, it's not meant to be cryptic, I must have been too terse here. Let $K=\operatorname{ker}(\phi).$ The stabilizer of each $y\in G(S)x$ is conjugate to the stabilizer of $x,$ so in fact all the stabilizers are $K.$ The orbit-stabilizer theorem applied to $G(S)/K$ (where the stabilizer is trivial) gives $|G(S)/K|=m.$ For a different argument see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128098/show-that-any-abelian-transitive-subgroup-of-s-n-has-order-n. By Lagrange's theorem, for $g\in G(S)$ the order of $[g]\in G(S)/K$ is divisible by $m.$ This gives $m[g]=0,$ i.e. $mg\in K.$

Comment: Aha! The Lagrange's Theorem argument is perfect. Since $G(S)/\operatorname{Stab}(x)$ has order $m,$ then for any $g\in G(S),$ $mg+\operatorname{Stab}(x)=\operatorname{Stab}(x),$ whence $mG(S)\subseteq\operatorname{Stab}(x),$ so $mG(S)$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Stab}(x),$ so that gives us the homomorphism $g+mG(S)\mapsto g+\operatorname{Stab}(x).$ Thank you for clearing that up! My group theory is evidently rustier than I'd realized.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help! Did you come up with this model yourself? If so, what inspired you? If not, where did you find it?

Comment: @CameronBuie: I came up with it by staring at your question and thinking about how the relevant implication could fail. The simplest way to get "countable union of finite sets is countable" to fail is to start with the second Fraenkel model. The problem is that there's a tree (the first $T$ described in the question) for which the model needs to provide infinitely many bits of information to give an antichain, without providing enough information to form a chain. So the model needs to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Very nice! I hope you plan to publish.

Comment: Thanks again so much for your help, Harry! I went ahead and posted a more detailed proof as an answer to [the parallel question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143524/22840).

Answer (score 1):

Upon further research--in particular, upon inspecting the numerical list of forms from Howard and Rubin's "Consequences of the Axiom of Choice"--I noticed that Howard and Rubin's text actually *references* Good and Tree's paper. I also see that the first statement above readily implies Form 10A from H & R, the second statement above is Form 216 from H & R, the third statement above is Form 10 from H & R, and I give proof in the question that the third statement implies the first, so that the first statement is again equivalent to form 10. Furthermore, I noted that form 10F from H & R is the following:

> *Every* $\omega$-*tree has an infinite chain*.

This clearly implies the second of G & T's statement above, and I suspect that it is what was intended by G & T, in the first place. Most notably, according to [this site](http://cgraph.inters.co/names-and-statements), H & R's text cites that Form 10 is stronger than Form 216, but that it was not known to be *strictly* stronger. This leads me to suspect (even more strongly) an error on G & T's part. Obviously, if it holds in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that every $\omega$-tree with an infinite antichain must have an infinite chain, then it *isn't* strictly stronger, but I'm unable to prove this or find any information confirming/denying this, so I suspect that it is an open question.

One thing I *was* able to find is that Keremidis published a proof (in Mathematica Japonica, Vol. 51, No. 2, pp. 175-178) that Form 9 from H & R (Every Dedekind-finite set is finite.), which is strictly stronger than Forms 10 and 216 in $\mathsf{ZF}$, is equivalent to the following statement:

> Every infinite tree has a countably infinite chain or a countably infinite antichain.

This readily implies the second of the statements from G & T, but cannot follow from it unless $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent.