# Suppose $G$ is a abelian, transitive subgroup of $S_n$. Prove that for all $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $G_x=\langle 1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, group-actions

Question: Suppose $G$ is a abelian, transitive subgroup of $S_n$.  Prove that for all $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $G_x=\langle 1\rangle$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$.

Attempt: Suppose $1\neq g\in G$ and suppose $xg=x$ for some $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Since $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, there is an $h\in G$ such that $x(h)=x_0\in\{1,\dots, n\}$.  Then,

$$\begin{equation*} \begin{split} (x_0)g & = ((x)h)g, \text{ by above equality} \\ & = ((x)g)(h)\\ & = h(x) \\ & = x_0 \end{split} \end{equation*}$$ Thus $g=1$, a contradiction.  Hence, $G_x=\langle 1 \rangle$, as wanted.

Comment: It's basically correct, but you seem to be getting very confused by the notation, with $x(h)$, $(x)h$ and $h(x)$. Also you haven't defined $x_0$. You need to say "let $x_0 \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$" before you choose $h$.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense about $x_0$.... is there a better or "cleaner" way to write the equalities?  I'm just trying to use that $G$ is abelian, essentially.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the notation "$\langle 1 \rangle$", when this is clearly the trivial subgroup?

Comment: To avoid confusion with notation use this notation:
$x^h=x_0$, $x^g=x$.
For example, your long formula would then be written like this
$$
x_0^g=(x^h)^g=x^{hg}=x^{gh}=(x^g)^h=x^h=x_0.
$$

Comment: @kabenyuk thank you, that is very helpful and a nice way to see the notation, in my mind, a bit better.

Comment: @CAB Force of habit, that's all.

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but very close: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128098/61691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. You could polish it a little bit by doing a direct proof, without setting up a contradiction.

---

Let $x\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\sigma\in G_x$.
Let $y\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
From transitivity we get a $\pi\in G$ with $\pi(x) = y$.
As $G$ is abelian, $\sigma\pi = \pi\sigma$, so
$$
\sigma(y) = \sigma\pi(x) = \pi\sigma(x) = \pi(x) = y\text{.}
$$
Since this is true for any $y\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we get that $\sigma = \operatorname{id}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\forall(g,h)\in G\times G_x\;ghg^{-1}gx=gx$$
$\begin{align}
&\therefore\;\forall g\in G\; G_{x}=g\cdot G_x\cdot g^{-1}\subseteq G_{gx}\\
&\therefore\;\forall g\in G\;\;G_{gx}\subseteq G_{g^{-1}(gx)}=G_x\\ &\therefore\;\forall g\in G\;G_x=G_{gx}\\
&\therefore\;G_x=\bigcap_{y\in\{1,\dots,n\}}G_y 
\end{align}$

Therefore, $G_x=\{e\}$ because each $G_x$ member fixes each $\{1,\dots,n\}$ member.